# How to deal with treatment variable when using inverse probability weighting (IPW)?

Tags: logistic, treatment-effect, inverse-prediction

I have a dataset which contains around 10,000 observations. I want to estimate the treatment effect (suppose the treatment variable is *T*, which is a dummy and outcome variable is *Y*, and *X* represents the covariates) using this sample. However, due to the lack of some crucial information, I can only use around 1000 observations out of these 10,000 to estimate the treatment effect. To make sure the treatment effect estimated from the 1000 observations can be generalized to the full 10,000 observations sample, I decide to use IPW to solve this issue. Suppose I use a dummy variable *Z* to denote whether this observation is selected.

In the first step, I want to run a logistic regression on whether an observation is selected for estimating the treatment effect. I run the following logistic regression (*Z~X*). My question is when calculating the IPW, should I also consider the treatment variable *T*? If so, the logistic regression would be *Z~X+T*, is that correct? Or should I calculate the IPW for the control and treatment groups separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the treatment affects whether the observation is selected, then you need to account for treatment somewhere in the IPW model. Including the treatment in the selection propensity score model is one way to do it. You could also estimate weights separately within each treatment group; when using a parametric model, *this is equivalent to a model with an interaction between treatment and every covariate*. So the difference between your two choices is whether you want only a main effect of treatment in your propensity score model or interactions between treatment and every covariate. Probably the best answer is somewhere in between, so it's a good idea to use a flexible model to model propensity scores to avoid making functional form assumptions; you can let a machine learning method like BART decide if interactions between the treatment and covariates are necessary.